# Not able to merge the data of multiple worksheets from multiple excels with same header of all the Individual sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA, Gone thourgh the many areas to understand my need but having some issues.

Goal:

---

I have 3 sheets like sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3 for all the files(20 excelsheets), It’s have same in all the spreadsheets. Now I have another file called Master where I need to merge all the sheets. Not in single sheets in master but for Master sheet also I have **3 sheets(Sheet1,sheet2 and sheet3)** as the heading is same for all the sheets

---

Problem i am facing

---

The below code is merging only first sheet called sheet1 but not other sheets sheet2 and sheet3

---

```
 Sub simpleXlsMerger()
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Excel\Path")

    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj

    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

    Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

    'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    bookList.Close
    Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to add a loop to go thorugh those three sheets foe every opened workbook

try this (not tested)

```
Option Explicit

Sub simpleXlsMerger()
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Dim iSht As Long
    Dim masterWb As Workbook

    Set masterWb = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Excel\Path")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
        With Workbooks.Open(everyObj) ' open and reference current workbook
            For iSht = 1 To 3 ' loop through sheets index from 1 to 3
                With .Sheets(iSht) ' reference referenced workbook sheet with current index
                    .Range("A2:IV" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=masterWb.Sheets(iSht).Cells(masterWb.Sheets(iSht).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
                End With
            Next
            .Close
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting Runtime error, "Object doesn't support this Property or Methond"

Comment: I really Dont know how to get line number for Run Time errors...Please suggest me if you have an idea

Comment: at the error prompt click "Debug" button and you'll be brought to the offending line

Comment: This line is the problem:.Range("A2:IV" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=masterWb.Sheets(iSht).Cells(masterWb.Sheets(iSht).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

Comment: I think the offending line is `With Worksheet`, which is a typo since the right object name should be`Worksheets`. But more precisely it should be `Sheets` which is the same object used in the subsequent line.  see edited answer

Comment: Got another error at the same line after clearing the above issue. "Subscript out of range" but when i debugged through the code, Master sheet filled up with the data from the sheet1 of first workbook then i encountered with the mentioned error

Comment: can anybody help on the above issue?